# How to make React-Router to render an interactive output from the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use `react-router` right now, with `express.js`. My final objective is:

- When a URL hits the server, it will use server-side rendering to render the output.
- Once in the client, future clicks on the `Link` component will cause `react-router` to render on the client (no need to do a full round trip to the server).

What I got so far:

- Make server rendering like [this](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/server-rendering.md).
- Make the `Link` component to work properly, when I render on the client.

My problem:

- Once I render on the server, the ouput is not interactive. I mean, no event handler is associated with the DOM. That's comprehensible. What I'm looking for, though, is a way to blend server and client rendering. I mean, the server renders the output but somehow it gets interactive in the client. If I get this, I'll be able to use `Link` on the client and that will fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `React.render(component, element)` on the client where `element` points to a DOM node that contains your server-rendered React markup and `component` is instantiated with the same props as on the server (and assuming the props/state matches all the way down), React will transparently upgrade your static markup into an interactive React app.

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/ddvdppeg/) that demonstrates this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/ddvdppeg/ (note that there is a 1 second delay before the markup is upgraded to an interactive app, but only for demonstration purposes).

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but I'll assume it's the answer because the JSFiddle is so straighforward and it just works. Thanks a lot.